# Access CaseFeed as a Chatter free License User

Tags: chatter, feeditem, chatter-feed, casefeed, collaborationgroup

1. I insert comment on CaseFeed logged in as a System admin Profile.
2. I have Chatter Free License User.
3. I want those comments can alse visible to Chatter free license user
   and can able to Comment on those feed.

Plz any Suggestions and Approaches for above Scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any possibility to access CaseFeeds for Chatter free licencse user. Please see [Click Here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_chatter.htm) .

Not sure, but you need to upgrade to chatter plus edition to see salesforce object.